# Combine 2 lists of pairs in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine 2 lists of pairs.

**List 1:**

```
dyndns = [('user1', 'dyndns1'), ('user2', 'dyddns2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', 'dyddns4')]
```

**List 2:**

```
ip = [('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]
```

I want to join List 1 to List 2, but only want to add the item from List 1 if it does not exist in List 2.
As you can see List 1 has user1, user2, user3 and user4, but List 2 only has user1, user2 and user4
The combined list has all users from List 2 as well as the extra users in List 1

**Combined List:**

```
combined = [('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ip_dict = dict(ip)
print([(user, ip_dict.get(user, dns)) for user, dns in dyndns])
```

This outputs:

```
[('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]
```

Comment: This is great if `ip` can't define any `users` keys not present in the `dns` list

Answer (score 2):

A lengthy discussion of de-duplicating while preserving sort order can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order/39835527#39835527). Applied to this case de-duplicating entries is trivially simple if you convert to a dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print(list(OrderedDict(dyndns + ip).items()))
```

Which outputs your desired result:

```
[('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]
```

For more context, your lists  are already correctly formatted to be sent to the `dict` (or `OrderedDict`) constructor, as they are lists of `key`, `value` tuples.

What we are doing is to build an `OrderedDict` from `dyndns` and `ip` lists combined which will ensure the keys are in the order defined in the `dyndns` list, but any values from `ip` will over-ride values defined in `dyndns` (because later values override earlier values). We then convert back to a list of tuples by calling `items` and casting to a `list`.

If order is not important (or if you are in python 3.6+), this can be simplified to:

```
print(list(dict(dyndns + ip).items()))
```

Comment: don't understand why you need dict?

Comment: @Ultraviolet For easy merge.

Comment: Agreed it's better as a dict. But `update` returns None so this raises an attribute error.

Comment: Fixed that @101

Comment: Matthew, how would the script look to combine the two lists and then print the output?

Comment: @KevinCrick See the other answer ^.^

Comment: @KevinCrick i added a print to the end. This is equally efficient at de-duplicating and printing to any of the other solutions.

Comment: @KevinCrick got this back down to a one-liner for ya.

Answer (score 1):

We get list of keys or users from `ip` (list 2)
and iterate on another list to check if the key is present in list 2 already, if not present add to the list.

```
ip = [('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]
dyndns = [('user1', 'dyndns1'), ('user2', 'dyddns2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', 'dyddns4')]
ip_keys = list(map (lambda x:x[0], ip))
for i in dyndns:
    if (not i[0] in ip_keys):
        ip.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to achieve the output. It used Python's **sorted()** function based on its **key** keyword argument.

```
def get_combined_users(list1, list2):
    usernames = set()
    combined = []

    for user in sorted(list2 + list1, key=lambda user: user[0]): # Do not use => list1 + list2
        if not user[0] in usernames:
            usernames.add(user[0])
            combined.append(user)

    return combined

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dyndns = [('user1', 'dyndns1'), ('user2', 'dyddns2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', 'dyddns4')]
    ip = [('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]

    combined = get_combined_users(dyndns, ip)
    print(combined)
```

#### Output

```
[('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', '1.1.1.4')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
def get(l1,l2):
    la1 = [i[0] for i in l1]
    la2 = [i[0] for i in l2]
    for i in la1:
        if i not in la2:
            l2.append(l1[la1.index(i)])
    return l1


print(get([('user1', 'dyndns1'), ('user2', 'dyddns2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), 
('user4', 'dyddns4')],[('user1', '1.1.1.1'), ('user2', '1.1.1.2'), ('user4', 
'1.1.1.4')]
))

#output:-- [('user1', 'dyndns1'), ('user2', 'dyddns2'), ('user3', 'dyndns3'), ('user4', 'dyddns4')]
```